# Impressive overview page and beamer handout mode

Tags: beamer

I've been playing with [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/). It allows you to do all sorts of funky eye-candy things. The overview page feature is useful, but it's awkward if you have many slides to one frame. The overview contains one page for each *page* of the PDF. It would be nice if I could automatically get a list of which pages are supressed by the `handout` option and pass that to impressive to have them ignored by the overview page. I'm sure this is a feature that will be put into Impressive soon, but for now, is there a hacky way to get a list of pages that `handout` ignores?

Comment: +1; I have 10 or so slides on some frames; then it's indeed rather useless if each page is shown in the overview.

Comment: In ConTeXt, I wrote the [overview module](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/announcing-the-overview-module/) to provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer myself. There's a [makebeamerinfo](https://github.com/jberger/MakeBeamerInfo) perl script that makes the `.info` file for me.